# activeMQ fileQueueCursor (heap size)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, activemq-classic, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I use AcviteMq v 5.9.1 and non-persistent message. My problem is

> OutOfMemory: heap size

I know that this kind of issue was on this site, but I can't find my specific issue. I know that non-persistent message are stored in memory, so I get this error. I also know that I can increase Xms/Xmx, but this is not fix the problem (when I get a little bit more messages, I might get this error too).

```
http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html
```

I read on activeMq site that there are 3 cursors, and fileQueueCurosr write stored message into file. I set up my configuration for this cursor, but it doesn't work either.

```
 <policyEntry queue="foo.bar.>">
    <pendingQueuePolicy>
        <fileQueueCursor />
    </pendingQueuePolicy>
  </policyEntry>
```

Maybe, somebody has similar problem and can help me with it? Or maybe this cursor is not enaugh and I have to set up something else?

-Xmx and Xmx default is set up 1GB/1GB.

**////UPDATE 23.04.15** after @kartik answer

```
<policyEntry queue="foo.bar.>" memoryLimit="10mb" (or 30mb) producerFlowControl="false">
        <pendingQueuePolicy>
            <fileQueueCursor />
        </pendingQueuePolicy>
      </policyEntry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use fileQueueCursor with memoryLimit broker can use. For example in below case, it is 1.5 GB total broker can use out of available RAM.
   " memoryLimit="1500mb"  producerFlowControl="false" >
2. Set Memory usage %. after that broker will push messages into KahaDB tmp files.

Comment: I decrease my Xmx/Xmx to 20M/20M, becasue I don't want to wait so long for "heap size" error. So I added this => memoryLimit="10mb" (or 30 as you menion, but it doesn't change anything) producerFlowControl="false". Moreover, I have memoryUsage="70". I notice that when memory usage is below 70 then everything works well,. When it comes to 70 (and higher I guess) then I get heap size error every time. I wonder if it possible to write the messages to tmp file when memory exceeds 70%? I guess that fileQueueCursor should works like that, but it doesn't.

Comment: What is your queue name, it should always start with foo.bar or if you want to apply for all queues put wild card >.

Comment: My queue is foo.bar (for test), but I check with '>' and is the same.

Comment: Make your consumer faster by higher prefech but it will increase memory need at client. Try async true for all options at producer/consumer side. Try if client_acknowledge with message.ack work better OR auto acknowledge with optimize acking on.

Comment: This configuration solved the problem and I found out that it not AMQ was the problem but something else. Thx for help.